# Max distance between polygons in a polygon set

Tags: python, shapely

I have a polygon set in GIS with a lot of polygons. My task is to find two polygons with max distance between them [two polygons that are the farthest/farthermost, my english is funny :( ]

This is my code so far, but I stopped because output gives me the the max value that is not correct. Help please. This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from shapely.wkb import loads
from osgeo import ogr


datoteka=ogr.Open("sth.shp")
sloj=datoteka.GetLayerByName("katastar")


udaljenosti=[]
for i in sloj:
    cestica1=loads(i.GetGeometryRef().ExportToWkb())
    for j in sloj:
        cestica2=loads(j.GetGeometryRef().ExportToWkb())
        udaljenosti.append(cestica1.distance(cestica2))


max_udaljenost=max(udaljenosti)
print max_udaljenost


datoteka.Destroy()
```

i know i have a lot of unnecessary stuff in the code but I'll fix that when i fix this maximum distance.

Comment: what's not correct about it?

Comment: how do you expect me to confirm that without the data? You need to make a MCWE that demonstrates this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No. Just hard code some *simple* geometries as WKT into a list. File input and output are not related to your question, so you should isolate them away from your MCWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is most likely an issue with how you iterate over the layer `sloj`. The thing is that if you write a code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from shapely.wkb import loads
from osgeo import ogr

datoteka = ogr.Open("custom.shp")
sloj = datoteka.GetLayer()

N = sloj.GetFeatureCount()
print(N)
for p in sloj:
    cnt = 0
    for q in sloj:
        cnt += 1
    print(cnt)
```

then this won't print `N` times the number `N`, but instead only number `N` followed by `N-1`. The reason is that `sloj` works as an iterator, thus when the outer loop is entered, it consumes the first element and the inner loop consumes all remaining `N-1` elements. Therefore the outer loop terminates on the next iteration since there is nothing left to iterate over.

In order to reflect this in your code, you could for example do (if the number of objects is not too large):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from shapely.wkb import loads
from osgeo import ogr


datoteka=ogr.Open("C:\Users\Sanja\Desktop\Desktop\Geof\Geof 
IV\BPP\podaci\katastar.shp")
sloj=datoteka.GetLayerByName("katastar")

L = [p.GetGeometryRef().ExportToWkb() for p in sloj]
N, max_dist = len(L), -1

for i in range(N):
    cestica1 = L[i]
    for j in range(i+1, N):
        cestica2 = L[j]
        max_dist = max(max_dist, cestica1.distance(cestica2))

print(max_dist)

datoteka.Destroy()
```

However, these distances are calculated in the lat/lon coordinates, i.e., they do not represent true distances on the globe. Nevertheless, if the objects in your layer don't span large areas of the globe, then the pair with the largest distance in the lat/lon coordinate system will most likely correspond to the pair with the largest "true" distance.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! I'll use this for my code. The problem was I didn't know why outter loop is executed just once, but now I get it. Thanks again!